# How can get userToken parameter for auth GDK from callback url

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk, google-mirror-api

I cannot get "userToken" parameter from the redirected callback url.

Under Glassware GDK authorization guideline like below I should have seen **“userToken”** parameter on redirected callback url after turned on our glassware.

**GDK Authentication Process**

*When users turn on your Glassware in MyGlass, they are redirected to your authentication URL. These requests include a query parameter named **userToken** that you need to use later.*

However, when i debug the redirected callback url on callback server, there had just **"code"** parameter.

It looks like the successful authorization flow of Mirror API under Glassware Mirror API authrization guideline like below. (Not Glassware GDK authorization flow)

**Authenticate the user**

*This initial sign-in returns an authorization result object that contains an authorization **code** if successful.*

I insert the informations like below on glassware submission web page.

**Client ID** = Client ID for **Service Account**

**Authorization URL** = https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=**code**&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/glass.timeline+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/glass.location&redirect_uri=http://www.aaa.com/auth/google/callback&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force&client_id=**Client ID for web application**

**Package Name** = Package Name from AndroidManifest.xml.

What i have to fix for getting "userToken" parameter on redirected callback url ??

Answer (score 1):

The `?userToken=` query parameter is not retrieved from the OAuth 2.0 redirect callback but from the URL that MyGlass uses to open the pop-up.

If the URL you gave the review team was something like `https://www.example.com/auth`, MyGlass will open a pop-up with this URL `https://www.example.com/auth?userToken=<USER_TOKEN>`. It is you responsibility to save this value until you can fully process the request.